Prove that for symmetric random walk $S_n$ it holds that $S_{min\{n,\tau\}}^2 - \min\{n,\tau\}$ is a uniform integrable martingale
I want to show that for a stopped symmetric random walk $S_n$ we have that $S_{min\{n,\tau\}}^2 - \min\{n,\tau\}$ is a uniform integrable martingale. Where $\tau = \inf\{n \ge 0 : S_n \in \{-a,b\}\}$.
So far I have only been able to show that $S_{min\{n,\tau\}}$ is uniform integrable since it is bounded by $\max\{a,b\}$.
Any help showing that $S_{min\{n,\tau\}}^2 - \min\{n,\tau\}$ is uniform integrable would be appreciated!

Recall that if $\lim_nM_n$ exists a.s., it is integrable and $\lim_nE[M_n]=E[\lim_nM_n]$ then $(M_n)_n$ is uniformly integrable.

how, would I know both of these criteria?

The sequence ${\min(n,\tau): n=1,2,\ldots}$ is u.i. because ieach of its terms is dominated by the integrable random variable $\tau$.

Here's a way to do this by doing a bit of a roundabout argument.
I'll denote $\min(a,b)$ by $a\wedge b$ for ease of writing.
First see that $\tau\wedge n$ is an increasing sequence of random variables. Hence, by MCT, you have that $E(\tau)=\lim_{n\to\infty}E(\tau\wedge n)$
Now, notice that as $(S_{n\wedge \tau}^{2}-n\wedge\tau)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Martingale, you have that $E(S^{2}_{n\wedge t})-E(\tau\wedge n)=0$ and as a conseqeunce
$$E(\tau\wedge n)=E(S^{2}_{n\wedge \tau})$$
Now, as $S^{2}_{n\wedge \tau}\leq \max(a^{2},b^{2})$, you have that $\lim\sup E(\tau\wedge n)\leq \max(a^{2},b^{2})$. This is enough to show that $E(\tau)=\lim_{n\to\infty}E(\tau\wedge n)\leq \max(a^{2},b^{2})<\infty$.
Now you have that $|S^{2}_{n\wedge \tau}-n\wedge \tau|\leq \max(a^{2},b^{2})+\tau$ for all $n$ and the RHS is now an integrable random variable. This proves uniform integrability.
